# Create or Edit New Loyalty Partner Product in Classic brings: Error ID: 892672159-2228 (273009397)

Tags: gack, loyalty-management

When I try to Create or Edit New Loyalty Partner Product in Classic, I receive the following Gack error Error ID: 892672159-2228 (273009397)

An internal server error has occurred
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!

Error ID: 892672159-2228 (273009397)

Why this error occurs? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have opened SF Support Case and this is the response from them.

[Loyalty application is not supported in Classic, only in Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.add_program_partner.htm&type=5)

So such gacks in Classic are expected and by design per Salesforce Support response

---

Still, I feel this would be better if there was some informative message like "This is not supported in Classic, please switch to Lightning Experience" instead of nasty Gack error id which doesn't tell anything neither gives a link to documentation that this is not supported. So I have opened an Idea on IdeaExchange for that

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Pk5WMUAZ/fix-the-internal-gack-id-in-salesforce-classic-loyalty-partner-product-editcrea